# Is there a difference between$ -(1000)$ and $(-1000)$?

Tags: arithmetic

Or are they equal? If they aren't, when one you use one and not the other?

Comment: For all practical purposes, they are equal.

Comment: They are obviously equal.

Comment: Why would you think they should not be the same? Have you got a particular definition that makes it non-obvious? What do you know of signed arithmetic?

Comment: They are equal, but brackets do matter:$-(1000)^2=-1000000$ but $(-1000)^2=1000000$

Comment: They are different expressions that evaluate to the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

it is $-(1000)=-(+1000)=-1000$ since $-(+)=-$ and $-1000=-1000$

Answer (score 1):

They are equal. You could choose to see $-(1000)$ as $-1 \times 1000$, and $(-1000)$ as $1 \times -1000$. But they both turn out to be $-1000$.